# Select and Insert Query Records in same query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT user_id, description, SUM( Credit ) AS cre, SUM( debit ) AS deb, 
CASE WHEN credit > debit
THEN SUM( credit - debit ) 
END AS del, price, created
FROM accounts
WHERE created
BETWEEN  '2013-11-04'
AND  '2013-11-11'
AND description LIKE  '%Amount Earned%'
OR description =  'S'
OR description =  'B'
GROUP BY user_id
```

1. Problem with this query is that this query is Selecting all records according to user_id from accounts table. I want to select records only created
   BETWEEN  '2013-11-04'
   AND  '2013-11-11'
2. I want to select these records and need to Insert records also in the same query

Requirement: I want to select record from accounts table from last week group by user_id, Sum(Debit) and SUM(Credit) and Del ->(credit - debit) put the Sum and Insert records in same accounts table.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into (other table ) 
  SELECT user_id, description, SUM( Credit ) AS cre, SUM( debit ) AS deb, 
     CASE WHEN credit > debit
     THEN SUM( credit - debit ) 
  END AS del, price, created
FROM accounts
WHERE 
( created BETWEEN  '2013-11-04' AND  '2013-11-11' )
AND
( description LIKE  '%Amount Earned%'
  OR description =  'S'
  OR description =  'B' )
GROUP BY user_id, created
```

Comment: One more condition in this query, select all records where del value is greater than 0, and if del is 0 then don't show that record